# How to access MediaElement's methods in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, maui

I'm learning .NET MAUI and I'm making an internet radio application. I'm using the **MediaElement** control from the CommunityToolkit package and that control has methods like `Play()` or `Stop()` in it and I'd like to use them in my ViewModel. They are so far only available from Code-behind after setting `x:Name` in XAML. And I would like to use these methods, but in my ViewModel specifically. How could I rewrite the code so that it preserves the MVVM structure?

**NowPlayingViewModel.cs**

```cs
namespace Rad.io.Client.MAUI.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(CurrentStation), "CurrentStation")]
    public class NowPlayingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...

        public StationInfo CurrentStation
        {
            get => currentStation;
            set
            {
                currentStation = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public NowPlayingViewModel(IRadioBrowserClient radioBrowserClient)
        {
            this.radioBrowserClient = radioBrowserClient;
        }

        public ICommand OnStopPressed => new Command(() => {
            mediaElement.Stop(); // <- How to call method Stop() available in MediaElement control?
            
        });

        public ICommand OnPlay => new Command(() =>
        {
            mediaElement.Play(); // <- How to call method Play() available in MediaElement control?
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

**NowPlayingView.xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace Rad.io.Client.MAUI.Views;

public partial class NowPlayingPanel : ContentView
{
    public NowPlayingPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void playStopButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mediaElement.CurrentState == CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Primitives.MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            mediaElement.Pause();
        } else if (mediaElement.CurrentState == CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Primitives.MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
        
    }
}
```

**NowPlayingView.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Rad.io.Client.MAUI.ViewModels"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:NowPlayingViewModel"
             x:Class="Rad.io.Client.MAUI.Views.NowPlayingPanel">
    ...
            <toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Grid.Column="1"
                ShouldShowPlaybackControls="False"
                BackgroundColor="DarkCyan"
                ShouldAutoPlay="True"
                Source="{Binding CurrentStation.Url}"/>
            ...
            <Button x:Name="playStopButton" Text="Play/Stop" Clicked="playStopButton_Clicked"/>

                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    
            </FlexLayout>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: That's a great idea!
Actually, because the _MediaElement_ is a UI component, I had similar problematics where I could bind some actions specifically in the ViewModel (media source control), and some not (volume, playback position). If you'd like to see it in action, I have published a complete series about MediaElement [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/10-play-music-with-mediaelement).